# PHP Form Validation with Javascript doesnt stop on return false

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to make a simple HTML form validation via Javascript

I have been struggling with this for a while now over a few examples, And no matter what I follow, My index page keeps loading after the button click on the form, I believe that I have put return false in the correct locations to break the rest of code execution, Any ideas why this is so? "My" code is below

Note: I have tried the novalidate attribute with the form, this deactivates the browser's validation but still sends me through to my index page, The ideal functionality should not load the index page and stay on the register page with warnings below the correct input fields

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["register"]))
{
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    echo "Welcome ".$user;
}

?>
```

**register.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form validation with javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <form novalidate method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="vform">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput" placeholder="Username">
            <div id="name_error" class="val_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="textInput" placeholder="Email">
            <div id="email_error" class="val_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="textInput" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="textInput" placeholder="Password confirmation">
            <div id="password_error" class="val_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" name="register">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Adding javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // GETTING ALL INPUT TEXT OBJECTS
    var username = document.forms["vform"]["username"];
    var email = document.forms["vform"]["email"];
    var password = document.forms["vform"]["password"];
    var password_confirmation = document.forms["vform"]["password_confirmation"];

    // GETTING ALL ERROR DISPLAY OBJECTS
    var name_error = document.getElementId("name_error");
    var email_error = document.getElementId("email_error");
    var password_error = document.getElementId("password_error");

    // SETTING ALL EVENT LISTENERS
    username.addEventListener("blur", nameVerify, true);
    email.addEventListener("blur", emailVerify, true);
    password.addEventListener("blur", passwordVerify, true);

    // Validation Function
    function Validate(){
        // Username Validation
        if (username.value == ""){
            username.style.border = "1px solid red";
            name_error.textContent = "Username is required";
            username.focus();
            return false;
        }
        // Email Validation
        if (email.value == ""){
            email.style.border = "1px solid red";
            email_error.textContent = "email is required";
            email.focus();
            return false;
        }
        // Password Validation
        if (password.value == ""){
            password.style.border = "1px solid red";
            password_error.textContent = "password is required";
            password.focus();
            return false;
        }

        // check if the two passwords match
        if (password.value != password_confirmation.value)
        {
            pasword.style.border = "1px solid red";
            pasword_confirmation.style.border = "1px solid red";
            password_error.innerHTML = "The two passwords dont match";
            return false;
        }
    }

    // event handler functions
    function nameVerify(){
        if (username.value != "")
        {
            username.style.border = "1px solid #5E6E66";
            name_error.innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }
    }

    function emailVerify(){
        if (email.value != "")
        {
            email.style.border = "1px solid #5E6E66";
            email_error.innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }
    }

function passwordVerify(){
        if (passwprd.value != "")
        {
            passwprd.style.border = "1px solid #5E6E66";
            passwprd_error.innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

**style.css**

```
#wrapper{
    width: 35%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #EFFFE0;
}

form{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

form div{
    margin: 3px auto;
}

.textInput{
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 28px;
    border: 1px solid #5E6E66;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn{
    padding: 7px;
    width: 100%;
}

.val_error{
    color: #FF1F1F;
}
```

Thanks a bunch for any help you can provide!

Comment: Doesn't `passwprd` typo? inside `passwordVerify` function?

Comment: Ah yes you are right, unfortunately it still pushes me into the index form on the click though :/

Comment: `preventDefault` thing, then.

Comment: What @Chay22 said: change `function Validate(){` to `function Validate(event){` and instead of `return false;` (or before those in addition) use `event.preventDefault();` to stop the submit event from continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to your form, attach form submit event to it and if validations get fails then you can use event.preventDefault(); to stop the submission of form.
Try the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


     <form action="your_file_name.php" method="post" id="myForm">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"  id="firstname">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" >
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function(event) {

 if($("#firstname").val()== "" || $("#lastname").val()== "") //Your validation conditions.
  {
        alert("Kindly fill all fields.");
        event.preventDefault();
  }
  //submit the form.
    });
   </script>
   </html>
```